# Open specific ViewController when recive push notification?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios8, push-notification, xcode6, navigationcontroller

I would set the opening off  us specific view by opening a push notification sent from parse.Using IOS 8.
How can i do that??
I used this code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
NotificationViewController *notificationViewController = [[NotificationViewController alloc] init];
[navController.visibleViewController.navigationController pushViewController:notificationViewController animated:YES];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I use this code

```
- (UIViewController*)topViewController {
    return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
}


- (UIViewController*)topViewControllerWithRootViewController:(UIViewController*)rootViewController {

    if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
        UITabBarController* tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:tabBarController.selectedViewController];
    } else if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:navigationController.visibleViewController];
    } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController) {
        UIViewController* presentedViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:presentedViewController];
    } else {
        return rootViewController;
    }
}
```

Called this way:

```
- (void) doSomething {
    UIViewController *topViewController = [self topViewController];
    NotificationViewController *notificationViewController = [[NotificationViewController alloc] init];
    [topViewController.navigationController pushViewController:notificationViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Don't forget to put this code on your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (when a user touches a notification with the app closed)

```
    NSDictionary *remoteNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
if (!remoteNotification) {
    UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (notification) {
        [self doSomething];
    }
} else {
    [self doSomething];
}
```

Comment: I did this but it stil doesn't work;I've edited this code:    - (void) doSomething {
    UIViewController *topViewController = [self topViewController];
    Mappa *notificationViewController = [[Mappa alloc] init];
    [topViewController.navigationController pushViewController:notificationViewController animated:YES];
}

Comment: What exactly isn't working? You called doSomething inside application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: right?

Comment: I called doSomething in didReciveRemoteNotification but it doesn't work.When i open the app from push notification it continue to open in mainView. In doSomething is it correct to have replaced the myViewController with notificationViewController?

Comment: If your app is closed, you need to use the last code in my response.